# Why mongoose gives error: "Mongoose error:[object Object]"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm a newbie for backend, especially for NodeJs, MongoDB and Mongoose. For handling errors I wrote a simple code like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongoDB = 'mongodb://localhost/NodeProject';
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');


mongoose.connect(mongoDB,function(err,err){
    if(err){
        console.log('mongoose error:'+err);
    }
    else{
        console.log('mongoose connected'+mongoDB);
    }
});
```

And I added a db variable to my main js file like this:

```
var db = require('./app_server/models/db');
```

I just want to see "mongoose connected" but it gives an error :

```
mongoose error:[object Object]
```

So what is [object Object] ?
What is happening here?

Comment: Instead of using `+` in `console.log`, use comma. This will allow you to see objects, e.g. `console.log('mongoose error:', err);`.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked.

Comment: Great! The reason is when you try converting an object to a string, it will result in `[object Object]`; you would have to use `JSON.stringify` to be able to see the object. When you pass an object to `console.log`, it does it under the hood for you.